# Year based WP Query

Tags: wp-query, date

I am am having a strange issue, trying to get year based posts in wp_query, when i do directly, 'year' => '2014' it works fine, but i have the year stored in a variable, $year, then i do 'year' => $year; it shows all posts, did echo of $year, shows 2014

here is the complete code I am using..

```
global $paged;
if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
    $my_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
else {
    if( get_query_var( 'page' ) )
        $my_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    else
        $my_page = 1;
    set_query_var( 'paged', $my_page );
    $paged = $my_page;
}

$setyear = '2014';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news_posts',
    'year'  => $setyear,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'press-releases'
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $my_page
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried double quoting the year or removing the quotes altogether?

Comment: The year value I am retrieving it from the URL, for example URL is domain.com/about-2014/ I am using php to get the value of php. I will post that code above.